# How are DNS queries and responses formatted?

Tags: text, dns

How does a DNS request look like, in plain text? Or is it encoded by some means, maybe sent as binary information not reversible to plain-text... A HTTP request in it's simplest form looks as follows

```
GET http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1
```

And a response header can be as simple as

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 3012
Content-Type: text/html
```

So, my question is, how are the simplest DNS queries and responses formatted? Thanks :)

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035#section-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a binary protocol. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-4 is a good link to get an idea (as provided in comments).

Comment: thanks :) i'm trying to make a domain name server so this helps alot my friend